# Checking if array is symmetric

Tags: java, arrays, symmetric

```
public class symm
{


/* 
 * Returns true if array A is symmetric.
 * Returns false otherwise.
 * n is the number of elements A contains.
 *
 * The running time of your algorithm is O(  ).
 * You may add a brief explanation here if you wish.
 */

 public static boolean symmetric( int[] A, int n )
 {
 return symmHelper(A, n, 0);

 }

private static boolean symmHelper(int[] A, int n, int i) {
if(n==1)
    return true;
if((n==2) && (A[i] == A[n-1-i]))
    return true;
if((i == n-1-i) && (A[i] == A[n-1-i] ))
    return true;    

if(A[i] == A[n-1-i] && i < n/2 )
    return symmHelper(A, n, i+1);

return false;
}  


}
```

Test cases:
I passed all the tests ecxept the fitst on I get no whenever I run it, I think the problem is that there are two 2s in the middle. And I'm not really sure about the code, I think it can be simplified. 
Is the running time o(log n)?

5 8 2 2 8 5 
YES

10 7 50 16 20 16 50 7 10 
YES

5 8 5 
YES

1000 1000 
YES

6000 
YES

10 7 50 16 20 16 50 7 1000 
NO

10 7 50 16 20 16 50 700 10 
NO

10 7 50 16 20 16 5000 7 10 
NO

10 7 50 16 20 1600 50 7 10 
NO

10 7 50 16 1600 50 7 10 
NO

Comment: But 5 8 2 2 8 5 *is* symmetrical.

Comment: Add a print command to your function so you can see what i and n are each time through the recursion. Then you can use that to help walk through your if() statements and see when each one is firing.

Comment: BTw, This check `if((i == n-1-i) && (A[i] == A[n-1-i] )) return true;` is redudant and can be reduced to `if(i == n-1-i) return true;` You could even combine this case with the `n == 1` case using the `||` operator.

Comment: @pamphlet oh yes I see your answer down there...

Comment: @popnoodles yes it is symmetrical, but my output was No. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex code makes for more mistakes. Thus, simplify it. Also, look for inequalities rather than equalities; it's easier to check for one mistake than for everything to be correct.

```
// A = array, n = size of array, i = looking at now
private static boolean symmHelper(int[] A, int n, int i) {

    if (i > n/2)     // If we're more than halfway without returning false yet, we win
        return true;

    else if (A[i] != A[n-1-i])    // If these two don't match, we lose
        return false;

    else    // If neither of those are the case, try again
        return symmHelper(A, n, i+1);
}
```

If I remember my O() notation right, I think this should be O(n+1). There are other tweaks you can make to this to remove the +1, but it'll make the code run slower overall.

Comment: @DiMono Isn't O(n+1)=O(n). Only the highest power of the poly in the O notation matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(A[i] == A[n-1-i] && i < n/2 )
```

That line right there is the problem. Because you're using an even number > 2 of values, when it gets to this line it skips over it because at that point i **=** n/2, rather than being less than it. So the function skips that and continues on to `return false`. Change it to this and you should be fine:

```
if(A[i] == A[n-1-i] && i <= n/2 )
```

Comment: Not really. Truth is you should return true if `i >= n/2`

Comment: @DiMono both are not working! The problem is as you said, because I'm using an even number > 2, I'm not really sure how to deal with that!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N;
    int i;
    boolean sym = true;

    N=input.nextInt();
    int [] numbers = new int [N];

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        numbers[i]= input.nextInt();
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(numbers[i]!= numbers[N-1-i]){
        sym=false;}
    }

   if(sym==true){
       System.out.println("The array is a symetrical array");
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("The array is NOT a symetrical array");
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This check is useless:

```
if((i == n-1-i) && (A[i] == A[n-1-i] ))
    return true;
```

Of course if the two indices are the same the values there will match.

Also you need to split this if in two:

```
if(A[i] == A[n-1-i] && i < n/2 )
    return symmHelper(A, n, i+1);
```

And return true if `i >= n/2`.

Otherwise what happens is that after i > n/2 (which means you already know your array is symmetrical), you do not go into that if and thus return false, which is wrong.

Comment: if I split them, it will return true if i >= n/2, even if the array  in symmetric, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N;
    int i;


    N=input.nextInt();
    int [] numbers = new int [N];

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        numbers[i]= input.nextInt();
    }
    i=0;
    while (i<N/2&& numbers[i] == numbers [N-1-i]){i++;
    }

   if(i==N/2){
       System.out.println("The array is a symetrical array");
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("The array is NOT a symetrical array");
   }
        }
```